# u-boot.cfg file in U-boot

Tags: u-boot, kbuild

I am understanding the U-boot build, it seems the selected config options in Kconfig are updated in u-boot.cfg file.

Can you guide to understand how it is created and the usage of this file(who will use this file).

Answer (score 0):

The current U-Boot configuration options are stored in file **.config**.

You can create a default configuration my using one of the filenames in **configs/**, e.g.

```
make qemu_arm64_defconfig
```

To adjust the configuation use

```
make menuconfig
```

https://opensource.com/article/18/10/kbuild-and-kconfig has some more detail about the internals of the Kconfig system.

Answer (score 0):

The u-boot.cfg file is produced when you build U-Boot. It is just there to let you see what config options were selected.

Normally you edit the configs/..._defconfig files to actually change the configuration of U-Boot for a board.